# How to implement telnet GUI for RoR web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, telnet

I want to create a feature on my web portal where a user can click a link to open a telnet session in the browser itself. I researched the [Net::Telnet](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/telnet/rdoc/Net/Telnet.html) library for Ruby. It has information on how to set up the connection.

But what about the web UI? 
How to leverage the `Net::Telnet` library on the rails web app.
I have Rails 4.2.0 with Apache Passenger running on a CentOS 6.6 machine.

Comment: Minor diction improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Because telnet is a streaming/serial type protocol and users will expect that type of experience, you might want to look into websockets or streaming http. The only other option would be to do polling to keep your view updated which seems like a very bad fit for a telnet client. Definitely an interesting problem. It appears that Net::Telnet behaves like a tcp socket connection so if you can wire that up to an http stream, which seems possible, you should be able to push it to a browser UI. Sounds like a cool project. Let me know how it takes shape.